# Make overriding method return a different type

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PetrolCar myCar = new PetrolCar();
        String mileage = myCar.getEngine().getMileage();

    }
}

class Engine {
    protected String var = "Engine";

    protected String getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }
}

class PetrolEngine extends Engine {
    protected String var = "PetrolEngine";
    protected String mileage = "0";

    PetrolEngine() {
        super();
        mileage = "100";
    }

    protected String getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }

    protected String getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
}

class Car {
    protected Engine engine;

    protected Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
}

class PetrolCar extends Car {
    protected PetrolEngine engine;
}
```

Obviously `myCar.getEngine().getMileage()` will not work because `getEngine()` will return an `Engine` instance, not a `PetrolEngine` instance. What is the workaround for this? I don't want to redefine `getEngine()` in all subtypes of `Car`, at the same time I would like to get back the more specific type `PetrolEngine` when I call `getEngine()` on an instance of `PetrolCar`, without having to type cast. Is this possible?

In other words, is there a way I can associate the `Engine` of `PetrolCar` to be a `PetrolEngine`? In the above case, it is creating two separate instance variables `engine`, one of `PetrolEngine` type inside `PetrolCar`, and another `Engine`, which I can access as `super.getEngine()` from inside `PetrolCar`. I don't want different variables. What I would like is that the code should know that the "`Engine`" of "`PetrolCar`" is a `PetrolEngine`.

**EDIT:** Changed MyCar to PetrolCar to avoid confusion which is leading everyone to believe that MyCar should be an instance of Car rather than a subtype.

Comment: Why do you need the extra `engine` member in `MyCar`? Does a `MyCar` have two engines?

Comment: You have not even Respected a single POO requirement !!

Comment: I am asking myself right now why you dont want getEngine() to return an Engine. For what reason?
And if it really has to be like this: Use a generic class as Tom Hawtin pointed out..
In addition: I would make an (abstract?) superclass DefaultEngine, which implements an Engine-Interface. Then pull up all the general Engine-methods, and override them in the descendants if necessary.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore.. exactly, I don't want two engines. But I want myCar.getEngine to return a PetrolEngine, and not an Engine.

Comment: @AdelBoutros.. What's POO? Cooked it up in a hurry, shouldn't need 2 getVars.

Comment: POO is a french abbreviation for (Programmation Orientee Objet), in English OOP (Object Oriented Programmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. They call it *covariant return* (starting from Java 1.5):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyCar car = ...;
        car.getEngine().getMileage();
    }
}

interface Car {
    Engine getEngine();
}

interface MyCar extends Car {
    PetrolEngine getEngine();
}

interface Engine {
}

interface PetrolEngine extends Engine {
    String getMileage();
}
```

Comment: This would not work because car.getEngine() returns an Engine, which does not have a getMileage() method. But I looked up Covariant return and the example wikipedia threw out gives me a way to do this. I guess I can override getEngine() and make it return a type-casted Engine. I'll try it out too. Thanks!

Comment: @Raze2dust `car.getEngine()` returns instance of `PetrolEngine` if type of `car` is `MyCar` -- that's *covariant returns* in a nutshell

Comment: In this case, MyCar is not a Car any more right? We are losing the information that MyCar is a subtype of Car. Am I missing it?

Comment: +1 Sorry, my mistake. It's. I just missed `extends`. Fixed. Try to run it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you turn `Engine` into an interface:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCar myCar = new MyCar();
        String mileage = myCar.getEngine().getMileage();
        System.out.println("The mileage is " + mileage);
    }
}

interface Engine {
    String getVar();
    String getMileage();
}

class PetrolEngine implements Engine {
    protected String var = "PetrolEngine";
    protected String mileage = "0";
    PetrolEngine() { mileage = "100"; }
    public String getVar() { return var; }
    public String getMileage() { return mileage; }
}

class Car {
    protected Engine engine;
    protected Engine getEngine() { return engine; }
}

class MyCar extends Car {
    protected PetrolEngine engine;
}
```

Comment: As probably every engine has a mileage, i'd also introduce a "DefaultEngine implements Engine", and derive concrete engines from DefaultEngine.
This allows to refactor common behavior up to a superclass.

Comment: But the thing is all engines don't have a mileage. Mileage is something specific to the petrol engine in my case. Is there a way I can get an instance of PetrolEngine when I call myCar.getEngine()?

Comment: It depends. How do you expect your program to behave if `mileage` is not supported by the current engine in the car? (e.g Do you want to print a message to the user? Safely ignore it? Upgrade the engine? Stop the car?)

Comment: @Raze2dust "Is there a way I can get an instance of PetrolEngine when I call myCar.getEngine()?" Yes. Consider *covariant return* types.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to skin a rabbit.

Most importantly, get (and set) methods tend to indicate uninteresting objects. Much better to put the behaviour in the object, rather than have a procedural script run outside.

The method may be appropriate to all engines, so could be moved to the base class.

You could subclass `Car` for different types of engine

`Car` could be made generic `class Car<E extends Engine> {`.

In unusual cases, a small visitor may be appropriate. Add a method to `Engine`, `public void accept(EngineVisitor visitor)` where `interface EngineVisitor { void visit(Engine engine); void visit(PetrolEngine engine); }`.

(Couple other comments: It's generally a good idea for a class to be either abstract or a leaf - extending concrete classes is usually bad. Implementation inheritance should generally be used sparingly, and `protected` very rarely indeed. If you intend fields not to change, mark them `final`.)

Comment: this is an overkill for the topic starter :)

Comment: Using generics seems to be a good idea in my case. I'll try to wrap my head around the visitor idea :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you either have to cast to `PetrolEngine` or, better yet, pull the `getMileage()` method up to `Engine`.

This might be useless toy example, but if it's real I'll point out that I would want fuel efficiency measurements whether the engine burned petrol, vegetable oil, or monkey urine.  The method makes sense on the higher class.

If you're worried about "calculating" it differently for different `Engine` types, make it abstract or make `Engine` an interface.

Comment: Pulling getMileage() out isn't what I am looking for because I am crazy and I want only PetrolEngine to have a mileage.. of course it is a crappy example.. but I hoped peeps would focus more on the intent. I guess I should have spent more time on refining the example rather than (trying to) explain it in words :)

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you reimplement the getVar method when it does the same work ? Do you even understand the way Extends work? You should read about class Inheritence in java.

Here is a working solution:

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCar myCar = new MyCar();
        String mileage = myCar.getEngine().getMileage();

    }
}

class Engine {
    protected String var = "Engine";
    protected String mileage = "0";

    protected String getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }

    protected String getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
}

class PetrolEngine extends Engine {

    PetrolEngine() {
        super();
        var = "PetrolEngine";
        mileage = "100";
    }
}

class Car {
    protected Engine engine;

    protected Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
}

class MyCar extends Car {

    MyCar() {
        engine = new PetrolEngine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have implemented getVar in Engine.. I had added getVar for some other purpose and forgot to remove it. Anyways, the point is I want mileage only for PetrolEngine.. I know it's not straightforward, and might not even make full sense, but in case there is some design pattern for this... (Generics work although it looks messy, and I Still have to try out Visitor as suggested by Tom)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a new class to represent your car (I assume that is what you mean by MyCar).  Surely your car is just an instance of Car but with the details specific to you?  I would suggest your car class should look like this:

```
public class Car {
    private Engine engine;

    public Car(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

}
```

Now if you want to instantiate your car you can do:

```
Car myCar = new Car(new PetrolEngine());
```

Next your Engine class should either be an interface or abstract, depending on whether or not you have some basic behaviour common amongst all engines, e.g.:

```
public abstract class Engine {
    private final String type;

    protected Engine(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public abstract String getMileage();
}
```

then for a PetrolEngine you do:

```
public class PetrolEngine extends Engine {
    public PetrolEngine() {
        super("Petrol Engine");
    }

    public String getMileage() {
        // Implement this however you calculate mileage for an Engine
        return "100";
    }
}
```

Note the use of the protected constructor in Engine, this forces all subclasses to explicitly call that constructor and therefore specify the engine type, which replaces your getVar methods.

If you really do want to have a separate class for your car that has a PetrolEngine, then you could do this:

```
public class MyCar extends Car {
    public MyCar() {
        super(new PetrolEngine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, by MyCar I mean a whole class of cars. I was going to write PetrolCar and stuff.. Anyway I get it, its a bad example :)
Nevertheless, if I call myCar.getEngine(), I'll still get an Engine and not a PetrolEngine.

Comment: If you do it like I have written above, calling myCar.getEngine will return an instance of PetrolEngine, because that is what was stored in the engine variable when you construct it. PetrolEngine is a sub-class of Engine, when you call any methods on the Engine, the under-lying implementation (in this case PetrolEngine) will actually do the work.  So you should never care what type of Engine it is, just know that when you call getMileage() it will actually be the method in PetrolEngine that is invoked.

Comment: I tried it, it is returning an Engine, not a PetrolEngine. I can typecast it of course. But I want to avoid doing it every time. Note that I do not want Engine to have a getMileage() method, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes I would do:

- Move the *getMileage()* Method up to the Engine class and return there a default value
- Just overwrite *getMileage()* when you need to return a different value
- Use int, float or double for mileage and not a number in a string
- You don't have to overwrite the *getVar()* Method in the subtypes again, when you return just this.var. This is already done in the Engine class

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an interface instead of a class for the **Engine** class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a new interface called IEngineWithMileage. It has one method called GetMileage(). Let PetrolEngine implement IEngineWithMileage. In your main method, check to see if the Engine implements IEngineWithMileage - if so, call GetMileage(), otherwise, continue on your merry way. Sort of like this (sorry, it's C#):

```
internal interface IEngineWithMileage
{
    int GetMileage();
}

internal abstract class Engine
{
}

internal class RegularOldEngine : Engine
{

}

internal class PetrolEngine : Engine, IEngineWithMileage
{
    public int GetMileage()
    {
        return 100; //your code goes here.
    }
}

internal class Car
{
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

internal class PetrolCar : Car
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var petrolCar = new PetrolCar();
        var engine = petrolCar.Engine;

        if (engine is IEngineWithMileage)
        {
            var mileage = (engine as IEngineWithMileage).GetMileage();
        }
        else
        {
           //do whatever you need to do if there is no mileage
        }

    }
}
```